# Create a equilateral triangle using SVG in HTML with base and height 100px

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create an equilateral triangle in SVG with base and height 100px. I'm not getting the exact output I need, below is the code sample:

```html
<svg id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <polygon points="50 15, 100 100, 0 100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's nice to know that the hight of an equilateral triangle is `side * Math.sqrt(3) / 2`. In your case `100 * Math.sqrt(3) / 2`. The resulting `points = 50 13.397, 100 100, 0 100`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap in a container and set the size as a percentage. Then it will be possible to adjust the size and the shape will be adaptive.

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <svg id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
             <polygon points="50 15, 100 100, 0 100"/>
        </svg>
     </div>
```

second option without using the container:

```html
 <svg id="triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                 <polygon points="50 15, 100 100, 0 100"/>
 </svg>
```

third option

Write syntax as per specification [polygon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)

The comma must separate the coordinate "X" and "Y"

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid gray;" >   
 
 <polygon points="50, 13.397 100, 100 0, 100"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Reply to comments

> The compiler still giving me an error that it is not a valid triangle.

To validate the file I added the required parameters

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
<title>Triangle</title>
</head> 
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 100 100"  >   
 
 <polygon points="50, 13.397 100, 100 0, 100/>    
</svg>
```

Download this file to the validator https://validator.nu/

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alexandr_TT. Thanks for your reply, but I have to do it by using SVG only, I can't use any container or another element, just SVG, this is the main challenge.

Comment: @Neeraj Sharma I will add the second option without using the container

Comment: that's really great of you. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hi Alexandr_TT, again producing incorrect output. Can we do it with paths only? Please don't use width and height.

Comment: @Neeraj Sharma I will make the third option you have a mistake in the ways

Comment: Hi @Alexandr_TT. The compiler still giving me an error that it is not a valid triangle. Even I have added width and height attribute to the SVG tag.

Comment: @Neeraj Sharma To validate the file, I added optional parameters here in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <polygon points="0 0, 100 0 50 100" fill="blue" stroke="red"/>
      </svg>
```